# OpenCV multiple frames into video

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to combine multiple frames into one video using opencv.
Is this possible?

My program can save multiple images but it can't combine them into one video.

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy

frame = 1
with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {'top': 40, 'left': 0, 'width': 800, 'height': 640}

    while 'Screen capturing':
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        frame += 1    
        name = 'C:/Users/samih/SublimePython/Game_Play_Recorder/Imgs/img' + str(frame) + '.png'
        cv2.imwrite(name, img)





        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

It should be able to convert all these images into one video.

Comment: Check out this [tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video) on writing/saving video

Comment: yes it is possible. CV has functions to write frames in video file. Video has to use the same size (width, height) as frames or you have to resize frames before you save it. But using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) can be easier - like `ffmpeg *.png output.mv4`

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [VideoWriter](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html). See the official tutorial on [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html), under **Saving a Video**.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,  480))
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    frame = cv.flip(frame, 0)
    # write the flipped frame
    out.write(frame)
    cv.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```